# Facebook JS SDK FB.Login() how do I get extended permissions?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, fbml

I am trying to get extended permissions with my FB Connect Application.

I was wondering how one does this with FB.Login() as I am not very knowledgable in JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FB.Login() docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) have an example:

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ONCLICK="fbLogin()" value="login">

function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        //user is logged in, reload page
        window.location.reload(true);
      } else {
        // user is not logged in
      }
    }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.

I did see that, however I am not sure how to integrate it with my website.

I want to have a custom login button of sorts, so I have a html button and an onclick call which calls FB.Login()

<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON ONCLICK="FB_Login()"> in the basic idea.

That works for basic permissions, but I also want to get the users email. The above code seems excessively complicated to get oe extra bit of info.

Thanks

Comment: Many Thanks ! Ill tick it shortly - perhaps you could clarify the workings such that I can develop my knowledge?

I have little experience in JS - this was given to me as 'the best way of doing things with fb' so im trying to learn as i go.

Can I assume to get the same fbml esque workings whereby on logging in my page is reloaded i can simply add something like document.reload()

Thanks

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean you want to reload a page once the user is logged in? You can use `window.location.reload(true)` for this (edited the answer).

Comment: it's not _response.session_ but **response.authResponse** !

Answer (score 5):

Please note that "perms" should be updated to "scope" otherwise will not work with the OAuth api

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

See [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Answer (score 1):

What I did, using the code from the [Developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login), instead of using the "`<fb:login-button>`", I used this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="FB.login(function(response){},{perms:'email,publish_stream'});">
```

And it works great.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using C# code then you can use this:

```
protected void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,publish_stream", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?'[0]);          
}
```